# Combine AJAX request to load new page with variables

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, variables

I currently have three stored JS variables (`wordChoiceOne`, `wordChoiceTwo`, `wordChoiceThree`). Now that I have these stored, I want to run a function called `saveUsername()`. This function should do the following:

Take the jQuery variables above and pass them into PHP **and** load the file `register-form.php` into the div `register-login-form`

So I currently have the following AJAX request, but this only handles the reloading of the form. I've never combined jQuery with PHP before so how can I add the part in this to pass the three variables?

```
function saveUsername(wordChoiceOne, wordChoiceTwo, wordChoiceThree){
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("login-register-form").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }

xmlhttp.open("GET","register-form.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

What do I add to this to pass the three variables and convert them to PHP vars like with a `$` sign?

Answer (score 1):

```
function saveUsername(wordChoiceOne, wordChoiceTwo, wordChoiceThree){
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("login-register-form").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }

xmlhttp.open("GET","register-form.php?one="+wordChoiceOne+"&two="+wordChoiceTwo+"&three="+wordChoiceThree,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Then PHP side, use `$_GET['one']`, `$_GET['two']` and `$_GET['three']`

Comment: perfect thanks, this is just what I was thinking but couldnt get the words to output correctly in the URL. Will try this and let you know.

Comment: Quick question as an extra... I want this page that loads in to immediately enact some code (concatenate the three strings and do some other bits). I want this event to be bound to the load of the page. I know this is possible using jQuery binding to the success of the AJAX page. But is this possible in PHP? What can I bind my next steps to when it loads?

Comment: `<?php echo implode('',$_GET); ?>`

Comment: Can you expand on that? I'm afraid I'm not sure what you mean this code to do?

Comment: this will concatenate all your $_GET params and output them.
wasn't it what you wanted to do?

Comment: I'm off to sleep, maybe open another question.
Good luck, and have fun coding! ++

Comment: It is but I actually want to do some other stuff to them first. I was more asking about how I run a PHP function based off the success of an AJAX call.